# Instantiate an object from a dynamically generated class

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation, dynamically-generated

I am currently trying to achieve something like this:
Based on this class, I try to create a new instance of the class Class<? extends AbstractValidator> returned by the method getValidator().

```
public abstract class AbstractEnumDefinition
       extends AbstractRequestFieldDefinition {

    private Vector<String> values = new Vector<String>();

    public abstract void define(String lang);

    protected void addEnumDefinition(String value){
        values.add(value);
    }

    public Vector<String> getValues(){
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends AbstractValidator> getValidator() {
        return new AbstractValidator() {
            @Override
            public boolean isValid(String value) {
                return values.contains(value);
            }

            @Override
            public String getDefaultValue() {
                return "";
            }
        }.getClass();
    }
}
```

Say I create this class:

```
public class LanguageDefinition extends AbstractEnumDefinition {

    public LanguageDefinition() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void define(String language) {
        addEnumDefinition("BEL-fr");
        addEnumDefinition("BEL-nl");
        addEnumDefinition("BEL-en");
    }
}
```

Later in my code, I call

```
new LanguageDefinition().getValidator().getConstructor().newInstance()
```

The class I am trying to instantiate here is not declared anywhere, but "generated dynamically"/"dynamically created" within the AbstractEnumDefinition class.

When trying to do this, I get an `java.lang.InstantiationException` for

```
be....servlets.model.extraction.filter.editor.AbstractEnumDefinition$1
```

I guess this is due to the fact that this Class has to be explicitly created before hand, and not referenced dynamically?

Is there some kind of solution that would allow me to not have to write one class per validator?

Thanks for the help,

Eric

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamically created class*? We're not sure if we understand you there.

Comment: May be absence of no-param constructor makes the getInstance() fail for this class. And that means that anonimous classes cannot be instantiated by reflection.

Comment: Just updated the question, to clarify things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only make assumptions since i don't see the code where you are actually using the class, but you should check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html

One thing it mentions is the instantiation can fail is the class is an abstract class (perfectly logical since you can't instantiate abstract classes).

Also, i don't see why you need to return the class and then create and object. Why not just define a Validator Interface and have your method return a Validator object.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I had a wild hope this might actually work, since it indeed is an abstract, but defined class within the code. I wanted to avoid the actual object creation in this scope, if possible, using only classes references and on-demand instantiation. Your solution will of course work, and I believe it will be my only option anyway. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

That does not work for anonymous classes as far as I know, you have to convert your class to a named inner class:

But even that will not work, properly because you might not have a default constructor. Inner classes get implicit constructor arguments to keep the reference to the enclosing class. Unfortunately Closures do not work so well in static languages.

In summary inner classes that are non-static can not be instantiate outside of an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: Agreed. I had a wild hope this might actually work.
Indeed, even with the default constructor, instantiate an inner class doesn't work, at least how I had hope it might.

Thanks for your help.